# FreePBX: Invalid Database Permissions. The error was: could not find driver

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

We are following this documentation for installing 'asterisk' and 'FreePbx' on ubuntu 14.

http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FOP/Installing+FreePBX+13+on+Ubuntu+Server+14.04.2+LTS

everything works go smothly except one thing, When we are executing last command

```
 ./start_asterisk start
 ./install -n
```

We are getting this error

```
root@dtm-asterix:/usr/src/freepbx# ./install -n
Assuming you are Database Root
Checking if SELinux is enabled...Its not (good)!
Reading /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf...Done
Checking if Asterisk is running and we can talk to it as the 'asterisk' user...Done!
Preliminary checks done. Starting FreePBX Installation
Checking if this is a new install...Yes (No /etc/amportal.conf file detected)
Database Root installation checking credentials and permissions..Error!
Invalid Database Permissions. The error was: could not find driver
```

Here is my odbc.ini

```
[MySQL-asteriskcdrdb]
Description=MySQL connection to 'asteriskcdrdb' database
driver=MySQL
server=localhost
database=asteriskcdrdb
Port=3306
Socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
option=3
```

We checked, We have php pdo installed on our system.

Comment: Why you are triing install Beta?

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/env php -m | grep -i pdo` and make sure that PDO is installed for CLI instance of PHP, and also that you have a pdo_mysql driver.

Answer (score 3):

```
apt-get install php-mysql
```

seems to fix the problem for me